# Display results of many-to-many relationships and separate results regardless of their id

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

How do you display results of many to many relationships and separate results regardless of their id?

```php
@forelse ( $papers as $paper )
<article class="article-feeds mb-4">    
    @foreach ($paper->activityTypes as $actType )

    <div class="flex ml-4" id="activitiesInformation">  
        <div class="flex-1">
            <div>
                <p class="font-bold">{{ $actType->activity_type }}</p> for {{  $paper->title }}
            </div>

                </div>
            </div>
    @endforeach

</article>


@empty

    <p class="text-xl font-display">You don't have any activities listed for you</p>

</div>

@endforelse
```

I have a blade file that displays paper's activities, but what I need is to display each of them like in a separate activity feed, regardless of their id, as they are grouped by their `paper_id` key, I want it to be  separated

[image]

For this example, I want to see

> Recommendation for Expedita sit.
>
> Publish Paper for Expedita sit.

to be separated from one another since they are different activity but they have the same paper id..

Furthermre,,

this is the activityTypes relationship, I'm talking about

```
  /*success here.*/
  public function activityTypes()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(ActivityType::class,
      'paper_activities',
      'paper_id',
      'activity_type_id')
    ->withPivot('creator_id','display_name','body','status')
    ->withTimestamps() ;
  }
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little clearer what output you are expecting? Maybe post your relationships and the controller method that is rendering the blade file please?

Comment: @party-ring explained it edited the questoin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I get your idea. What you want is to get all the `activity types` related to a `paper` and each `activity type` on its own card.

To achieve that, from your Controller you can pass a new variable called `$activity_types` that you will fill like this:

```php
//assuming you are returning it from the index method

public function index()
{
    $papers = Paper::all();

    $activity_types = $papers->flatMap->activityTypes;

    return view('papers.index')
        ->with('activity_types', $activity_types);
}
```

also your blade should look something like this

```html
@forelse ( $activity_types as $activity_type )
<article class="article-feeds mb-4">    
    <div class="flex ml-4" id="activitiesInformation">  
        <div class="flex-1">
            <div>
                <p class="font-bold">{{ $activity_type->activity_type }}</p> for {{  $activity_type->paper->title }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

@empty

<p class="text-xl font-display">You don't have any activities listed for you</p>

@endforelse
```

Make sure you have a relation to Paper from the ActivityType model.